# ZMQ HTTP Server - empty Request

Tags: c, zeromq

While reading on ZMQ, I encountered this link - [A Web Server in 30 Lines of C](http://hintjens.com/blog:42). Highly motivated, I tried running the code and it does indeed print "Hello, World!"

Here's the problem: I never quite get the puts (request); to print anything. Essentially, I was looking for being able to send back some data based on query parrams. Example: http://localhost:8080/hello?myname=mho

response would change with `sprintf` of the name.

I believe I am not completely able to understand the code (:( just 30 lines!).

Any useful links on how the CZMQ is handling the frames? I am not sure, I am able to make good sense out of the inline documentation in the headers. 
Any pointers? Happy to read through please.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's pretty neat, but it's not an HTTP server - it doesn't understand anything about HTTP, especially not how to parse a query string.

You can certainly use 0MQ to send messages very simply.  The [zguide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/) has examples of many patterns in many languages - should be everything you need.  You need to write both a client and server (really a sender and a receiver) to send anything meaningful over 0MQ.  If you're hoping to use a generic http client like curl or wget, then use a real HTTP server instead of 0MQ.  Many scripting languages let you launch an HTTP listener in a single line of code.  Choose what best fits your needs.  If you do use 0MQ, there is an IRC channel on Freenode where you can get help.